# Disable escape key navigation in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

When typing the escape key on Flutter web, Flutter performs `Navigator.of(context).pop()`. How can I disable this functionality?

Here are the scenarios I tested which all resulted in consistent functionality:

- Chrome on Mac, Edge on Windows, and in DartPad 1.20.0
- `MaterialApp`, `CupertinoApp`, and `WidgetsApp`
- Debug mode and Release mode

I can disable it using `WillPopScope`, but this also disabled pressing the back button in the browser. I still want to allow users to navigate using the browser, so this is not a viable option.

Side question: Does anyone know why this is default functionality? This is not expected behavior on a website (excluding popup menus).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Flutter web** (and desktop too) uses <kbd>Esc</kbd> shortcut to dismiss modal dialog or popup menu. This binding is defined at application level in [WidgetsApp.defaultShortcuts](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsApp/defaultShortcuts.html) and, unfortunately, affects Navigator too. Of course for navigation between pages keyboard shortcuts should be somewhat different, but for now **Flutter web** status is **beta** and some features are still under development.

As a workaround, we can remove this shortcut from `MaterialApp`:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final shortcuts = Map.of(WidgetsApp.defaultShortcuts)
      ..remove(LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.escape));
    return MaterialApp(
      shortcuts: shortcuts,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

and have to restore one locally as needed:

```dart
  Future<void> openDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    final shortcuts = Shortcuts.of(context).shortcuts;
    final key = LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.escape);
    shortcuts[key] = WidgetsApp.defaultShortcuts[key];
    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Alert Dialog"),
          content: Text("Dialog Content"),
        );
      },
    );
    shortcuts.remove(key);
  }
```

Comment: maybe you can help in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73178225/how-to-ignore-a-specific-pointer-event-in-flutter-desktop-app) similar question ?

Comment: It seems that in later versions of Flutter the shortcut map keys are type ShortcutActivator, not LogicalKeySet. So you need something like shortcuts.removeWhere((key, value) => key.triggers!.contains(LogicalKeyboardKey.escape));